# Faye, websocket connection problems: can't establish connection with ws://localhost:9292/faye

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, faye

I've set up my Faye server, running alongside my rails server, like this tutorial tells me to:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/

No strange behavior, until I uncomment that line

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
```

Firebug then gives me the error in the title of this question.  Visiting localhost:9292/faye and /faye.js gives me what I'd expect, and (apparently) there isn't any problem with the javascript_include_tag that references that .js file.

I have to use bundle exec, per this error message when I start faye:

``` $  rackup ./config.ru -E production -s thin -p 9292
/Users/newcreation/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in ``block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.4.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.0. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError) ```

My config.ru looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'faye'

require File.expand_path('../config/initializers/faye_token.rb', __FILE__)

faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, you need at least version 0.7 to support websockets.  http://blog.jcoglan.com/2011/11/28/announcing-faye-websocket-a-standards-compliant-websocket-library/  This meant updating rubygems, for me, and re-running bundle install.  I also needed to change my .ru file to include the following:

```
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
```